# Proof Green's theorem $F(x,y)=(x-y)i+xj$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-spaces

I was reading on Green's theorem and have appreciated the concept. Given a question, I think, I can solve it.But I came across a question that reads:

Verify the Green's theorem for **the vector given by:**
$F(x,y)=(x-y)i+xj$

and the region R bounded by the unit circle,
$C:r=(\cos(t))i+(\sin(t))j;$ $0\leq t\leq 2\pi$.

How do I prove Green's theorem **given a vector field**.

Comment: It sounds like you're really being asked to apply Stokes' theorem (that the two theorems have been confused is understandable; they really say the same thing just with slightly different terminology and notation). Do you think that could be the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He's not asking for you to **prove** Green's theorem, but to **verify** it. This means computing $$\int\limits_C \vec{F} \cdot d\vec{s}$$ and $$\iint\limits_{R} \left( \frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial P}{\partial y} \right) \, dA$$ and see that they are equal. In your case we have $P=x-y$ and $Q=x$. Note that $$d\vec{s} = \frac{d}{dt} (\cos (t), \sin(t)) = (- \sin(t), \cos(t)).$$ Do the appropriate calculations and check the results.